# Resolve ambiguity of the [heap] tag between the data structure and the memory zone

Tags: discussion, tags

The [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap) tag description currently reads:

> A heap (data structure) is a tree that is ordered with respect to depth.
>
> Heap can also refer to process memory set aside for dynamic allocation.

which covers two very different use cases:

1. The data structure
2. The memory zone

I wish we would split it into:

1. [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap): memory zone, because it currently contains most posts by far:

   - [Which is faster: Stack allocation or Heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation)
   - [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)
2. [heap-data-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-data-structure) (?):

   - [Heap vs Binary Search Tree (BST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147242/heap-vs-binary-search-tree-bst)
   - [Real world applications of Binary heaps and Fibonacci Heaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767863/real-world-applications-of-binary-heaps-and-fibonacci-heaps)
   - [What do I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python)

There seems to be no conceptual relation between the two meanings of 'heap': [Why are two different concepts both called "heap"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap)

There is already a [heap-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-memory) tag which I propose be merged into [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap) if we disambiguate like I proposed.

Comment: Please separate your two proposals: a) there should be separate tags [heap-memory] and [heap-data-structure] b) there should not be a tag [heap], since it will perpetuate the ambiguity. Users must choose whether they meant [heap-memory] or [heap-data-structure].Corroborating point b), in 2/2019 someone created an unnecessary tag [heaps-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heaps-algorithm)

Comment: ...also there's a tag [heapsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heapsort), which corresponds to your proposed case [heap-data-structure]. Are most heap-data-structure-based algorithms about sorting/merging/insertion/pivoting? This is a mess. How should we clean it up?

Comment: Heap in the context of data structures usually refers to min-heap and max-heap and binary-heaps or heap-trees (a binary tree that is either min-heap or max-heap). The most accurate tag would either be [binary-heap] or [heap-tree].

Comment: The term “heap” refers to the data structure. The memory area should be referred to as the “free store”. This will be difficult to disambiguate, given how widespread the sloppy/incorrect usage is.

Comment: @smci hi there, I don't have the time to work on this right now, feel free to make edits and move it forward as you feel better, cheers.

Comment: I don't believe the problem is how SO uses the tags, but how the terms are used by the software industry. SO can't fix that.

Comment: I'm with Cody here. "Heap" should in my opinion refer to the data structure in the first place, not in the second place.  As the "heap" is more popular than free store, when referring to the dynamic memory pool, `heap-memory` is probably easier to find as a tag than alternatives. I frequently retag new questions when they have `heap` but are not about the data structure. The situation has improved since this question was asked. There aren't that many `heap` tagged questions anymore that are about heap *memory*.